# IndexError in Python3

Tags: python, list

I have the following MWE:

```
def get_files():
    file_list = ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth']
    return file_list

def set_names(orig_flist):
    file_list = []
    for i in range(len(orig_flist)):
        file_list[i] = orig_flist[i]
    return file_list

set_names(get_files())
```

When I run it, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "privpub.py", line 11, in <module>
    set_names(get_files())
  File "privpub.py", line 8, in set_names
    file_list[i] = orig_flist[i]
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

I don't understand what's going on. Can somebody explain me, please?

Comment: Note, that your loop in `set_names` simply copies values from one list to another. this can be simply done by `file_list = list(orig_list)`. In case, you do not mind, that those two list would point to the same data structure, you could also use `file_list = orig_list`. In that case if one list would be changed (e.g. a value appended), the other one would change (as it points to the same list).

Comment: Yes, I know that. The original function did something different, but I simplified it to get a MWE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to assign a value to an index in the list that does not exist yet:

```
file_list = []
for i in range(len(orig_flist)):
    file_list[i] = orig_flist[i]
```

You will want to use `append` in order to lengthen your list like so:

```
file_list = []
for i in range(len(orig_flist)):
    file_list.append(orig_flist[i])
```

Comment: So the indexes must first exist in order to be assigned?

Comment: Exactly, you can only assign a value to `my_list[i]` if `i` is less than `len(my_list)`.  Otherwise, you need to use `append()`, which adds the item to the end of the list by adding 1 to the length of the list.